# Using TabBar and separating XML data by category in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I want to use TabBar and I'm going to use many different TableView.

What I want to do is, as soon as the main application instance is created, 
* a big XML file should be loaded 
* Create TableView instance for each category(which includes array to save XML data)
* Loop through XML data and add one by one to proper TableView's array

So after this process, all TableView instance have an array which contains XML data only belongs to its category.
But I can not find where to do this since I'm using TabView template from IB.
Should I do all that programmatically??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make use for NSXMLParser for parsing the XML data and store te parsed data in a NSMutableArray. Alternatively you can also use touchXML. Check this 
[link](https://github.com/schwa/TouchXML) for more details about touchXML. Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not the answer I wanted. But thanks anyway. I wanted ask WHEN to parse XML file & add different items to each ViewController.